# SQL. The intricate JOIN between two tables

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I have 2 tables:**users** and **subscribers**. The relationship of the user to the subscriber is a **many-to-many**.

[image: table users]

[image: table subscribers]

I know how to get all users:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

And I also know how to get subscribers to a given user by his id (for example id=1):

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN subscribers ON id = user_id WHERE user_id = 1
```

But I need these results are not separately but together.

That is, I want to create a query to get *all users*.
But in addition to their properties, result of the query must contain a *property* that shows each user is subscriber or not.
Something like this:

[image: table subscribers]

And of course I would like to avoid the use of subqueries. It would be great to use only a JOINs.If this situation it is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the subscriber table map to a true/false value?

Comment: Is this MS Access? Might be helpful to tag as such if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT u.*, 
        CASE WHEN s.user_id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as IsSubscriber 
FROM users u 
   LEFT JOIN subscribers s ON u.id = s.user_id
```

...since `s.user_id` will be made `null` by the `left join` when the user is not in the `subscribers` table.

Comment: Thanks but here is the query which I needed: SELECT u.*, CASE WHEN s.user_id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS isSubscriber
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN subscribers s ON id = subscriber_id and s.user_id=1

Answer (score 0):

i updated your query to result what u want.

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastname, WHEN s.user_id IS NULL 'false' else 'true' END as IsSubscriber.
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN subscribers s 
   ON u.id = s.user_id 
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, COUNT(subscribers.user_id) != 0 AS isSubscriber
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN subscribers ON users.id = subscribers.user_id
  GROUP BY users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname
```